# Javascript variable never gets assigned

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following javascript but for some reason my var response is always set to default value of false even though result is true

```
var response = false;

connection.query('SELECT * FROM Something WHERE something = ?', [req.body.something], function(err, results)
{
    if (results.length == 0)
    {
        response == false;
    }
    else
    {
        hashedPassword = results[0].password;

        var comparePassword = encrypt.comparePassword(req.body.user.password, hashedPassword, function(err,result)
            {
                if (err) {throw error;}
                response == result;
                console.log("res=" + response);
                console.log('here ' + result);
                res.send(result);
            }
        );

    }

    console.log("response " + response);
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like it is because `comparePassword` is asyncronous.

Comment: Yes, and what user: robnick has mentioned in his answer. The assignment operator is `=` not `==`

Comment: comparePassword is async. I have a callback in there so it needs to wait for the response before continuing. Also is it best to put the res.send within the callback. If i put it outside it will run immediately right?

Comment: Yes, `res.send(result);` needs to be inside the callback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is wrong -->

```
response == result;
```

It should be:

```
response = result;
```

The double == is for testing conditions, a single = is for assignment.

Answer (score 0):

```
 response == result
```

will not assign to `response`. Are you sure that this is what you inteded?

Answer (score 0):

change your code to and try::

```
var response = false;

connection.query('SELECT * FROM Something WHERE something = ?', [req.body.something],  function(err, results)
   {
if (results.length == 0)
{
    response == false;
}
else
{
    hashedPassword = results[0].password;

    var comparePassword = encrypt.comparePassword(req.body.user.password, hashedPassword, function(err,result)
        {
            if (err) {throw error;}
            response = result;
            console.log("res=" + response);
            console.log('here ' + result);
            res.send(result);
        }
    );

}

console.log("response " + response);
})
```

This particular operator `==` is used while setting some condition inside loops or generally,and it will not change the value of the variable, and `=` is for assignment,which will change the value of the variable.